# Custom and locally stored icon (png) fails to load

Tags: html, windows, leaflet

I am a new to leaflet.js and I am now following the Leaflet API reference documentation. I am having an issue showing my custom icon.  I created a simple test icon of size 20x20 pixel named: testIcon.png. I used windows paint and saved it as png in the folder where the html page is stored.

```
        var myIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'testIcon.png',
            iconSize: [20, 20]
        });
```

I then created a marker using my custom icon and added it to the map, as shown below:

```
marker_1 = L.marker([36.209625, -95.464610],{icon: myIcon}).bindPopup("<b>Marker_1</b><br>BC1E").addTo(mymap);
```

And the custom marker does not show.  If I remove the text: ",{icon: myIcon}" from the code above the default marker (blue one) does show.  I have tried adding an absolute path to the png as per other post but still marker does not appear.

Thanks

Comment: Please use the [network monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) of your browser's developer tools and see what kind of network request the browser is making in regards to the icon's `.png` file, as well as what kind of error or response.

Comment: The network monitor states that the png file was not found, error 404.

Comment: That's your problem then. What kind of environment do you have for this? Are you relying on `file:///`, do you have any kind of local webserver?

Comment: I tried the file:/// setting and it did not retrieve the png.  I also tried the network path like http://127.0.0.1/F/... and it also failed.  I made sure that the folder with the png is shared on the network also.  This is all running on my private network with one computer running a python/Flask program to produce the web page and another opening a web browser to view the map.

Comment: You'll have to debug your python/flask webserver, check its logs, double-check that it can serve resources such as the image, see why it's returning 404s when asking for the image, etc. There's nothing wrong on the JS/Leaflet side of things.

Comment: In chrome I get the message: "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///..."